# Mod rewrite, append directory as parameter

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, apache2

I'm wondering how to do directory rewriting where the directory gets appended as a parameter regardless of the remaining url.

For example, if I have urls like these:

```
example.com/peter/lois/stewie.php
example.com/peter/lois/brian.php?drinks=martinis
example.com/peter/lois/quagmire/meg.php
```

and I need them to rewrite to

```
example.com/lois/stewie.php?person=peter
example.com/lois/brian.php?drinks=martinis&person=peter
example.com/lois/quagmire/meg.php?person=peter
```

how do I go about doing that?

Thanks!

**EDIT**

So I have it implemented like this in the sites-available file:

```
RewriteRule ^/([a-z0-9]+)/lois(.*) /lois$2?person=$1 [QSA,L]
```

but instead of returning like

```
example.com/lois/stewie.php?person=peter
```

it's returning like

```
example.com/peter/lois/stewie.php?person=peter
```

So it's putting the parameter at the end of the url like it should, but it's not dropping the earlier directory.

Answer (score 0):

mod_rewrite would work well for this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9]+)/(.*\.php) /$2?person=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Thanks a ton for the help.  I'm having one more issue I added to my question above.